# StrongSwan, Let’s Encrypt and a FreeRadius Server

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, strongswan, freeradius

i config StrongSwan + with Let’s Encrypt  ssl work fine but when i connect it to FreeRadius server i got error in 4 response and client side get error `user authentication failed`

```
13[NET] received packet: from 5.212.174.225[4500] to 134.119.183.101[4500] (144 bytes)
13[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
13[CFG] sending RADIUS Access-Request to server 'server-a'
06[MGR] ignoring request with ID 4, already processing
13[CFG] received RADIUS Access-Reject from server 'server-a'
13[IKE] RADIUS authentication of '111' failed
13[IKE] EAP method EAP_MSCHAPV2 failed for peer 102.127.111.2
13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 4 [ EAP/FAIL ]
```

and my ipsec.conf

```
config setup
  strictcrlpolicy=yes
  uniqueids=never
conn roadwarrior
  auto=add
  compress=no
  type=tunnel
  keyexchange=ikev2
  fragmentation=yes
  forceencaps=yes

  ike=aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes256gcm16-sha256-ecp521,aes256-sha256-ecp384
  esp=aes256-sha1,aes128-sha256-modp3072,aes256gcm16-sha256,aes256gcm16-ecp384

  dpdaction=clear
  dpddelay=180s
  rekey=no
  left=%any
  leftid=@ikev2.raway.net
  leftcert=cert.pem
  leftsendcert=always
  leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  right=%any
  rightid=%any
  rightauth=eap-radius # this uses radius authentication
  # rightauth=eap-mschapv2
  eap_identity=%any
  rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
  rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
  rightsendcert=never
```

my ipsec.secret

```
ikev2.raway.net : RSA "privkey.pem"
```

my strongswan.conf

```
charon {
    load_modular = yes
         plugins {
                  include strongswan.d/charon/*.conf
    eap-radius {
          accounting = yes
         servers {
    server-a {
      address = 134.119.183.102
      secret = Ramin
      auth_port = 1812   # default
      acct_port = 1813   # default

    }
  }
  }
  }
  include strongswan.d/*.conf
  }
```

Comment: I like the subject. Mind adding GPG there too? ) O_o

Comment: Hi
np i will add GPG  as tag

Comment: You should check the log of the FreeRADIUS server (or start it in debug mode). There is either a misconfiguration there, or it's simply that username and/or password are wrong.

Comment: Hi
i check the log only warning about nl_passowrd